# prove by $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition (involving $\infty$) that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^n = +\infty$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

prove by $\varepsilon - \delta$ definition (involving $\infty$) that $\lim_{n \to \infty} n^n = +\infty$
According to notation,
$(\forall C > 0)(\exists \Delta > 0)(\forall n \in \mathbb{R})(|n| > \Delta): n^n > C$
Hence, we need to find $\Delta$

Then:  $n^n > C \implies n > \sqrt[n]{C}$
$C > 0 \implies \sqrt[n]{C} > 0 \implies n > 0$, hence
$|n| > \sqrt[n]{C}$,
so $\Delta = \sqrt[n]{C}$

But seems like it's not a proof since we have $n$ (not a fixed number) on right side.
What's wrong? Thank you

Comment: "$(\forall n \in A)$" what does that mean?

Comment: If $C\geq 1$, take $\Delta=C$ for example and otherwise take $\Delta=1$.

Comment: Indeed, $\Delta$ cannot depend on $n$. Also, your proof is incorrect as it shouldn't start by assuming $n^n>C$. At best, it is OK as a draft, in a tentative to find a suitable $\Delta$. Also, check the definition of limits, since $|n|>\Delta$ makes little sense.

Comment: @Falcon sorry, my bad, should've just write $\forall n \in \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$n\log{n}>\log{C}$ should be your criterion.

your derivation is not correct.

Generally it should be:

$(\forall C>0)(\exists N)(n>N\implies n^n>C)$.